# how to get values of templatefield in gridview as an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am trying to access all my template filed values from code behind as an array.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No" meta:resourcekey="TemplateFieldResource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# (Container.DataItemIndex + 1) %>"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to bound the default text with the values that comes from following.

```
protected void grdOffice_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label l = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1");
        //get list of number array from label1
        //and replace each number with another value
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do...The `Text` property of `Label` controls are string not arrays. Your question is confusing

Comment: i want to get my gridrow's S.No. templatefield 1,2,3.. as an array as {"1", "2", "3"..}and replace them with some other values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but if you want to get the values of your *S.No*-cells in an array, you could try to make use of the `DataBound` event of your `GridView`:

```
protected void gv_DataBound ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    string[] ids = this.gv.Rows
        .OfType<GridViewRow> ()
        .Where ( r => r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
        .Select ( r => ( (Label)r.FindControl ( "Label1" ) ).Text )
        .ToArray ();
}
```

Please be aware that you don't change the text of your labels, if you change these values in the array.